# Unboxing issues

Tags: java, autoboxing, unboxing

I have a class that extends the LinkedList class.
Here's an excerpt of the code:

```
class SortedList<Integer> extends LinkedList<Integer> {
      int intMethod(Integer integerObject){
          return integerObject;
      }
}
```

This is expected to return the auto-unboxed int value. But for some reason, the compiler throws an error that says that the types are incompatible and that the required type was int and the type found was Integer. This works in a different class perfectly fine! What gives? :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you have `<Integer>` after `SortedList`.

Usually you use `T` for type parameters: `class SortedList<T>`, but you used `Integer` instead. That is, you made `Integer` a type parameter (which shadows the `java.lang.Integer`).

Your class, as it stands, is equivalent to

```
class SortedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
      int intMethod(T integerObject){
          return integerObject;         // <--  "Cannot convert from T to int"
      }
}
```

Remove the type parameter and it works just fine:

```
class SortedList extends LinkedList<Integer> {
      int intMethod(Integer integerObject){
          return integerObject;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've declared `Integer` as a generic type parameter for the `SortedList` class. So when you refer to `Integer` as a parameter of the `intMethod` method, that means the type parameter, not the `java.lang.Integer` type which I suspect you meant. I think you want:

```
class SortedList extends LinkedList<Integer> {
    int intMethod(Integer integerObject){
        return integerObject;
    }
}
```

This way a `SortedList` is always a list of integers, which I suspect is what you were trying to achieve. If you *did* want to make `SortedList` a generic type, you would probably want:

```
class SortedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {
    int intMethod(Integer integerObject){
        return integerObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked very well. I knew I should have read up on generics before messing with that. Serves me right. :)