# Custom Class in List Adapter

Tags: java, android, oop, listadapter

I'm having some trouble understanding how scope is affecting my code. I can't seem to access the public attributes of a public class.

I created a custom class `ArtistPacket` which has a block of information I would like to send to my custom adapter (`ArtistListAdapter`).

The custom class is below:

```
public class ArtistPacket{

    public String name;
    public int id;

    public ArtistPacket(String name, int id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

It is defined in `MainActivityFragment`, where I create an `ArtistListAdapter` which takes these `ArtistPackets`.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment{

...

ArtistListAdapter<ArtistPacket> artistListAdapter  = 
  new ArtistListAdapter<ArtistPacket>(getActivity(), artistData);

...
```

I then define the `ArtistListAdapter` and `getView`

```
private class ArtistListAdapter<ArtistPacket> extends ArrayAdapter<ArtistPacket>{

    public ArtistListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ArtistPacket> artists){
        super(getActivity(),0,artists);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

...
```

In the `getView`, I need the `name` and `id` from the `ArtistPacket` object (in this case `artist`). So I try calling

```
ArtistPacket artist = getItem(position);    
textItemContent.setText((CharSequence) artist.name);
```

But I get a compile error. In the debugger, it appears as if the full object is coming through - it just doesn't seem like the Adapter access the `name` or `id` attribute.

The error I get is:

```
Error:(98, 58) error: cannot find symbol variable name
where ArtistPacket is a type-variable:
ArtistPacket extends Object declared in class      
  MainActivityFragment.ArtistListAdapter
```

Is there an issue with scope in my implementation? Why would the Adapter not be able to see the contents of the `ArtistPacket` object if it is plainly seen in the debugger?

Here's the full getView:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Find the artist packet at a given position
        ArtistPacket artist = getItem(position);

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textItemContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_content);
        ImageView imageViewContent = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image);

        textItemContent.setText((CharSequence) artist.name);
        imageViewContent.setImageResource(artist.id);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: are you extracting the ArtistPacket instance from the artists list?

Comment: Can you show how you are creating the object `artist`?

Comment: can you post the whole getView ? What kind of errors are you getting

Comment: I think the ArtistPacket is extracted from `getItem(position)` method, and the right objects are showing up in the debugger.. I figure there's an issue with scope? The compiler allows me to manipulate the object as I see fit - just no access to its attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtle yet important answer to this.

The following class definition:

```
private class ArtistListAdapter<ArtistPacket> extends ArrayAdapter<ArtistPacket>
```

can be broken up to be better understood.

```
ArtistListAdapter<ArtistPacket>
```

Implies that the `ArtistListAdapter` is *defining* the type argument as `ArtistPacket`. This means that anytime ArtistPacket is referenced, it is referencing this type declaration - not the class defined above.

On the other hand,

```
extends ArrayAdapter<ArtistPacket>
```

Implies that the `ArtistListAdapter` extends an `ArrayAdapter` which *uses* the aforementioned ArtistPacket class.

In other words, the first <> is about *defined* types, while the second <> is about *used* types.

Thus, I used the following declaration:

```
private class ArtistListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArtistPacket>
```

Which implies the `ArrayAdapter` will be extending the `ArtistListAdapter` using the type `ArtistPacket` - without confusing the situation by defining it's own, local, ArtistPacket type.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255643/extending-generic-classes)