# How to override java list methods?

Tags: java, list, class, methods, overriding

I'm working on a java project where i need to use lists of different types that I create (Student ,school ... for example).

The problem is that I need to use some list methods with this types(or classes) like "containe" for Ex ...

I try to override this methods by creating my own list(arraylist or vector) which is Extended from java list ... but I have many problems because I want to use this new list(my list) with different types .

This how I extends myList from java list:

```
public class myList extends ArrayList<Object>{

public myList() {
}
    /***methods***/
}
```

and this how I use it :

```
public class newclass(){
       .
       .
       .
    myList<student> sl=new myList<student>();
       .
       .
```

But it does not work. So what is the right way to do this.

and thanks.

Comment: two sidenodes. Classes do start with capital letters following the java naming convention. second, don´t make this custom `List` a rawtype by defining the generic as `Object`, this will and can only cause troubles later on(which is also your problem). Make it `MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending Generic Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255643/extending-generic-classes)

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, but maybe all you need is implement comparable in your object, so sort and other methods work ... reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3718515/2101088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/):

```
public class myList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
...
}
```

This way you can create your own list of whatever you want like this:

```
myList<student> sl = new myList<>();
```

**Response Update:**

> how to make get -for example- return the same type in declaration
>   -which is  instead of the type Object

**Response with your list**

```
myList<student> sl = new myList<>();
sl.add(new student());
student s = sl.get(0);
```

**Response with an `ArrayList`:**

```
// But it works also with an ArrayList which implicitly mean that you have no need 
// to create your own implementation of an ArrayList
List<student> sl = new ArrayList<>();
sl.add(new student());
student s = sl.get(0);
```

Comment: Can you please write the overrided `contain` for a type(object)  `student` wich is defined by `String firstName ; String lastName;`.

Comment: could you please clarify I don't understand your question

Comment: you have no need to override the contains method, simply implement properly your equals method in your class student

Comment: i want to override the methods of list (contain,get ...) to work with different types of objects (i.e how to make `get` -for example-  return the same type in declaration -which is `<student>` instead of the type `Object`) , so how to do this ?! @NicolasFilotto

Comment: Maybe you want to overload by adding public boolean contains(T element) and then your class definition will be something like public class myList<T extends MySuperType> extends ArrayList<T>

Comment: @M.os.i answer updated, once again you have no need to create your own imp of an ArrayList