# When I override the "put(K key, V value)" in a TreeMap, how can I change "value"?

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I extend a TreeMap, override "put()", and do something equivalent to:

```
public class MyMap<K, Integer> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer put(K key, Integer value) throws ClassCastException, NullPointerException {
        java.lang.Integer newValue = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(123);
        super.put(key, newValue); // <--- error message here
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

error message:
*no suitable method found for put(K, java.lang.Integer)... java.lang.Integer cannot be converted Integer.*

I know it has something to do with generics. Altering the "value" in an overridden "put()" seems like a reasonable thing to do, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: As a general best practices thing, it'd probably be better design to make `MyMap` contain a normal `TreeMap` rather than subclassing `TreeMap` and violating its specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when declaring  **MyMap**  you tell the Java compiler that you have two generic types: "**K**" and "**Integer**". Therefore, "**Integer**" is not the **java.lang.Integer** numerical class but a generic type which can be **any** class. As **java.lang.Integer** is not necessarily your generic "**Integer**" type, then the Java compiler issues the error.

This example would do the trick:

```
public class MyMap<K> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer put(K key, Integer value) throws ClassCastException, NullPointerException {
            java.lang.Integer newValue = java.lang.Integer.valueOf(123);
            super.put(key, newValue); 
            return newValue;
        }
    }
```

Just another example that compiles but makes no sense to use (just for you to better understand what's going on):

```
public class MyMap<K, Integer extends java.lang.Integer> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer put(K key, Integer value) throws ClassCastException, NullPointerException {
            Integer newValue = (Integer) java.lang.Integer.valueOf(123);
            super.put(key, newValue); 
            return newValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `Integer` type parameter shadows `java.lang.Integer`.

The solution is probably to just drop the type parameter for the key of your class (since you seem determined to have `java.lang.Integer` as value type anyway).

```
class MyMap<K> extends TreeMap<K, Integer> {
    ...
}
```

Very similar question: [Unboxing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912171/unboxing-issues)